# SQL to_char need both integer and decimal in different case

Tags: sql

I got a return from DB give me both intrger and decimal. Let's say:

select dollar from table

sometimes dollar is an integer (1, 2) and sometime it is a decimal(1.54,2.32). If I do:

to_char(dollar,'99999999.99'), when it is decimal, it is ok. However, if it is integer, i got like 1.00 or 2.00.

I don't want to have useless 0 if the data is integer. How can I do that? If it is integer, just put integer and if it is decimal, put decimal.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the data type doesn't change, so you are talking about an integer value stored in a fixed or floating point representation.  Probably the easiest way is:

```
select (case when to_char(dollar, '99999999.99') like '%.00'
             then to_char(dollar, '99999999')
             else to_char(dollar, '99999999.99')
        end)
```

That is, do the conversion.  If the last three characters are ".00", then do the conversion without them.  If you don't like double conversions, you can do this with arithmetic too:

```
select (case when 100*cast(dollar / 100 as int) = dollar
             then to_char(dollar, '99999999')
             else to_char(dollar, '99999999.99')
        end)
```

However, I always worry that comparisons between integers and floating values might be off by some very minor amount, so I prefer the first method.